# Template conversion operator priority & constness

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I have something along the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo;

struct Test
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const //  <----- This const is what puzzles me 
    {
        std::cout << "Template conversion" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }

    operator Foo*()
    {
        std::cout << "Pointer conversion" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;

    if (t)
    {
        std::cout << "ahoy" << std::endl;
    }
    bool b = (bool)t;
    Foo* f = (Foo*)t;
}
```

It builds fine, but when I run it, while I would expect to get

```
$> ./a.out
Template conversion
Template conversion
Pointer conversion
```

I instead get

```
$> ./a.out
Pointer conversion
Pointer conversion
Pointer conversion
```

If I remove the const, or make the Test instance const, then everything works as expected.
More precisely, the overload selection seems to make sense strictly when both operators have the same const qualification.

13.3.3.1.2 point of the standard makes me think I should get an identity conversion, converting to a bool, using the template conversion operator instantiation with a `T` = `bool`, though there is obviously a subtlety hiding somewhere. Could someone enlighten me as to what rule comes into play here?

Comment: operator Foo* has higher priority than template operator, and Foo* is implicitly convertible into bool, so the compiler picks Foo* overload rather than the template one.

Comment: Shouldn't a potential instantiation creating an identity conversion be of higher priority?
It seems that the constness is mostly what makes the correct conversion being selected

Comment: apparently not if it is templated

Comment: @Creris That's incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing conversion sequences, the conversions on the parameters are considered before the conversion of the result type.  The implicit object parameter (the `this` pointer) is considered as a parameter, and a qualification conversion (`Foo -> Foo const`) is worse than the identity conversion on the implicit object parameter.  From **[over.match.best]**:

> 1 - [...] a viable function F1 is deﬁned to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> — for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that, [...]

So a non-`const`-qualified member conversion operator will always be better than a `const`-qualified one, even if the result conversion is exact on the latter.

Comment: Ok that makes sense then!
Thanks a lot for dubbing the standard in order to make it more readable :)

Answer (score 6):

The relevant rules are defined in [over.match.best]:

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   `F2` if for all arguments *i*, ICS*i*(`F1`) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS*i*(`F2`), and then
>   (1.3) — for some argument *j*, ICS*j*(`F1`) is a better conversion sequence than ICS*j*(`F2`), or, if not that,
>   (1.4) — the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
>   entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination type.

Let's just look at the first `bool` case. We have two viable candidates:

```
Test::operator T<bool>() const;
Test::operator Foo*();
```

Both are called with a non-`const` `Test`. For the 2nd overload, no conversions are necessary - the conversion sequence is simply Exact Match. However, for the first overload, the implicit `this` argument needs to undergo a qualification conversion from `Test` to `const Test`. Thus, the second overload is preferred - we do not get to the second step which discusses return type.

If we dropped the `const` however, the viable candidates become:

```
Test::operator T<bool>();
Test::operator Foo*();
```

Here, both candidates are equally viable with identical conversion sequences, but the `bool` template is preferred since the conversion sequence from the return type `bool` to `bool` (Identity - the highest rank) is a better conversion sequence than from `Foo*` to `bool` (Boolean Conversion - the lowest).